# Javascript asynchronous for complex calculation but not ajax calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to modify data (some algorithm but not an ajax call) before doing a server call `$http.post` inside the service/factory method. Or can I also do it in the controller before calling service/factory? Can I simply do it like below or do I need to use any callbacks?

```
// controller
data = modify_data(data); //This is not ajax call but may take some seconds to complete so dont know if I can do this way or pass any callback
promise = MyService.create(data);
```

Comment: the modify_data function. Is it asynchronous? Meaning that, for example, you  call setTimeout inside of it?

Comment: I dont know if it is asynchronous or not. What I know is, it will take some seconds to complete the tasks. No settimeout etc but it encrypts data so not  sure how much time it will take.

Comment: Then it is quite probably synchronous and then you can use it this way, unless you want to introduce asynchronicity for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As long as modify_data is not asynchronous, you shouldn't have an issue.  Data will have it's value before making the service call.

Comment: I dont know if it is asynchronous or not. What I know is, it will take some seconds to complete the tasks. No settimeout etc but it encrypts data so not  sure how much time it will take.

Comment: So, is it not asynchronous if its some data manipulation (not server call) which might take time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can but you may freeze the user interface which is not desirable.

If you want to not freeze user interface you have to modify the inside of your function modify_data and cut the process using setInterval method or rather $interval with angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

To make this working your modify_data will have to return a promise which will be resolved only when your  process will have ended.

And don't  forget to use the $interval.cancel() in order to clean your interval!

So the external code will look like this :

```
var defer = $q.defer();
// controller
modify_data(data).then(function(data){
    MyService.create(data).then(function(){
        defer.resolve();
    }, function(){
        defer.reject();
    });
});
return defer.promise;
```

Note that i use a $q.defer() to handle the resolution of MyService.create();

If you need some help to cut your modify_data process with $interval we'll need the code of it.

Comment: Seems its a perfect answer. Let me try this.

Comment: How to make modify_data return a promise ?

Comment: Same that i did use **var defer = $q.defer();** at then end use **return defer.promise;** and when your set of setInterval() have finish running use **defer.resolve(data);** Assuming the "data" is the variable holding the result in modify_data, so it will get pass in the .then where i call MyService.create